# IBM Cloud_deployment failure_Node RED

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am trying to use the Node Red in IBM Cloud. I have a Lite account on the platform but currently no app installed. When I try to deploy it after installation, I get :

```
Status : failed
```

I went over 128 for memory allocation. In the log, I get this error message :

```
Error restarting application: Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100005, message: You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app requested more memory than availableShowing health and status for app Node RED ....
```

How could I correct this error without creating another account?

Comment: What is your deployment target for the Node-Red app? IBM Cloud offers you to deploy on IBM Kubernetes Service, Red Hat OpenShift, Cloud Foundry and Code Engine.

Comment: It could be one option to upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go account. See the account types and their limiations on this page: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts

Comment: My deployment target is "Cloud Foundry"

Comment: As a lite account you need to stay under 256 MB of Cloud Foundry memory. Be sure you really have no other Cloud Foundry applications running. Maybe also try to reduce the memory that you want to allocate for the Node-Red app ...

Comment: How can I reduce a memory ?

Comment: The second bullet in the how to fix it section, explains how to reduce the memory of a Cloud Foundry app: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-ts-cf-apps#ts_outofmemory

Answer (score 0):

The second bullet in the "how to fix it" section, explains how to reduce the memory of a Cloud Foundry app: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-ts-cf-apps#ts_outofmemory

Let me copy it here:

To reduce the memory that your apps use, use either the IBM Cloud console or the Cloud Foundry command line interface.

If you use the IBM Cloud console, complete the following steps:

1. Select your app from the resource list. The app details page opens.
2. In the runtime pane, you can reduce the maximum memory limit or the numbers of app instances, or both, for your app.

If you use the command line interface, complete the following steps:

1. Check how much memory is being used for your apps:

   `ibmcloud cf list`

   The ibmcloud cf list command lists all the apps that you deployed in your current space. The status of each app is also displayed.
2. To reduce the amount of memory that is used by your app, reduce the number of app instances or the maximum memory limit, or both:

   `ibmcloud cf push appname -p app_path -i instance_number -m memory_limit`

   Restart your app for the changes to take effect.